# Need help fixing a function for drawing hexagons

Tags: java

I've got a program that can hexagonal tiles using images that are loaded into it. It creates these tiles images by replacing any pixels outside the hexagon with transparent pixels using a function called inHex(). This works.

Now I want to create a border on the inner edge of the hexagon. So I modified a copy of inHex(), changing the &&s to ||s, and adding two lines for the flat edges. The problem is that only the upper borders get drawn.

I've tried changing the order of the statements, and replacing all of the ors with separate if statements, no dice. Using System.out.print line in the loop I know hexEdge() doesn't return true when it should except for the upper lines.

```java
    public boolean hexEdge(int x, int y)
    {
        /**
         * returns true if the coordinates are inside the hexagon bounded by the width and height of the tile
         */
        double slope = (tileHeight/2.0)/(tileWidth);
        boolean inside=false;
        //check in acordance to sides
        if (x<(tileWidth/2 +1) )
        {
            inside= 
                    ( y == (int)(0.25*tileHeight-slope*x) ) ||//this works
                    ( y == (int)(0.75*tileHeight+slope*x) ) ||
                    (x==0 && y>(int)(0.25*tileHeight) && y<=(int)(0.25*tileHeight) );
        }else {
            int x2=x-tileWidth/2;
            inside =
                    (y == (int)(0+slope*x2) )||//this works
                    (y == (int)(tileHeight -slope*x2 ) )||
                    (x==tileWidth-1 && y>(int)(0.25*tileHeight) && y<=(int)(0.25*tileHeight) );
        }
        return inside;
    }
```

Comment: I dont see what kind of logic says if I turn && to II I'll get the perimeter. Better show the inHex so that we know what we are talking about - with your slopes and everything we dont get anything

Comment: I tried completely commenting the part of program that turned the color transparent, so it should turn the outside of the hex all black, only the top turned black and the bottom still turned transparent. It looks like a compiler problem at this point so I'm going to try restarting my computer.